# How do I create a function that properly formats the DOM for a 'nested' comment section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a module that includes *nested comments*. The data returned from my `ajax` request is formatted, roughly, like this:

```
  items: Array[3]
      0: Object
         Children: Array[3]
         0: Object
            Children: Array[2]
       1: Object
         Children: Array[3]
         0: Object
            Children: Array[2]
```

I've written a recursive function that finds all the parent and child comments, and appends the list to another element on the page:

```
    function findChildren( root ) {

      if( root.length >= 1 ) {

         $.each( root, function( key, parent ) {

              units.comments.push( '<div id="root-comment-' + parent.id + '">' + parent.comment  + '</div>' );

              if( parent.children.length >=1 ) {

                $.each( parent.children, function( key, child ) {

                    units.comments.push( '<div id="child-comment-' + child.id + '">' + child.comment  + '</div>' );

                    if( child.children.length >= 1 && child.children != null ) {

                        findChildren( child.children );

                      }

                  });

               } 

            });
     }

   } findChildren( parents );
```

The **problem** with  `findChildren` is that is appends a flat list of elements. **EDIT** I know I'm closing the `<div id="root-comment">`.

```
   <div id="parent-comment"><p>Some Comment</p></div>
   <div id="child-comment"><p>Some Comment</p></div>
```

What I would like is a nested list of elements

```
   <div id="parent-comment"><p>Some Comment</p>
       <div id="child-comment"><p>Some Comment</p></div>
   </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something like [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) would make this much easier.

Comment: Well, you close your div before you do the recursive part, what do you expect?

Comment: @Ryan, thanks for the link, I'll take a look at Knockout— I'm trying to stick with jQuery/Javascript for this project

Comment: @DaveNewton, I know that. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this sort of thing where you leave the `<div>` open while handling the nested parts and then close it afterwards:

```
 function findChildren( root ) {
      if( root.length >= 1 ) {
         $.each( root, function( key, parent ) {
              units.comments.push( '<div id="root-comment-' + parent.id + '">' + parent.comment );
              if( parent.children.length >=1 ) {
                $.each( parent.children, function( key, child ) {
                    units.comments.push( '<div id="child-comment-' + child.id + '">' + child.comment );
                    if( child.children.length >= 1 && child.children != null ) {
                        findChildren( child.children );
                      }
                    units.comments.push( '</div>' );
                  });
               } 
            units.comments.push( '</div>' );
            });
     }
   } findChildren( parents );
```